# Where am I dereferencing a NULL pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, hashtable

there is the def of the Hash Table

```
typedef struct pair
{
    char* key;
    int value;
}pair;

typedef struct node
{
    pair* p;
    struct node* next;
}node;

node* hash_table[HASH_SIZE];    /*pointer to Hash Table*/
```

and there is the implemented of init_data

```
void init_data()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < HASH_SIZE; i++)
    {
        hash_table[i]->p = (pair*)malloc(sizeof(pair));
        if (hash_table[i]->p == NULL)
            printf("Error: in index %d ", i);

        hash_table[i]->p->key = NULL;
        hash_table[i]->p->value = 0;
    }

    curr_size = 0;
}
```

and the compiler send me a this message de - referencing NULL pointer
why?

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: Your hash table is a pointer `node*` but you didn't initialize it with `malloc`. By the time you do `hash_table[i]->p`, the error occurs.

Comment: @MatheusPortela But isn't that `hash_table` globally declared as any array `node* hash_table[HASH_SIZE];`?

Comment: You never allocated any memory for `hash_table[i]`.

Comment: @ArdentCoder In the code provided, `hash_table` is an array of `node*`. The array itself `hash_table` is initialized but its elements `hash_table[i]` (of type `node*`) haven't. Then, de-referrencing with `hash_table[i]->p` raises an error since `hash_table[i]` is `NULL`.

Comment: @MatheusPortela I got it now. Thanks!

Comment: so how do I fix it? @MatheusPortela

Comment: regarding: `hash_table[i]->p = (pair*)malloc(sizeof(pair));`  in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest removing that cast.

Comment: regarding: `node* hash_table[HASH_SIZE];`  This ONLY allocates an array of pointers.  The code needs to set each of those pointers to an instance of `node` before trying to initialize those node contents

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Error: in index %d ", i);`  1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  2) since the error is coming from a C library function, should also output to `stderr`, the text reason the system thinks the error occurred. You might want to look into: `perror()` or `strerror( errno )`

Answer (score 0):

MatheusPortela has already discussed the problem in the comments. Here is the solution:

After declaring `node* hash_table[HASH_SIZE];`

Allocate memory for `hash_table[i]`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < HASH_SIZE; ++i)
{
    hash_table[i] = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
}
```

This should remove the segmentation fault. But you can also build the connections between the nodes (`next`) inside that loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the code provided, `hash_table` is an array of `node*`. The array itself `hash_table` is initialized but its elements `hash_table[i]` (of type `node*`) haven't. Then, de-referrencing with `hash_table[i]->p` raises an error since `hash_table[i]` is `NULL`.

You probably want to do some initialization of `hash_table` before actually using it. Something like this should do the trick:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < HASH_SIZE; i++) {
    hash_table[i] = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (i > 0)
        hash_table[i-1]->next = hash_table[i];
}
```